# RxJS Merge Observable in Callback

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I need a little help with making a function return an observable. I have a function (let's call it `mainFunction`), that calls an async function (let's call it `getAsyncWithCallback`) and executes a callback. Part of the callback is an async call that returns an observable (let's call it `getData`).

`getAsyncWithCallback` is part of a library and I cannot change it.

This is what I have:

```
mainFunction(){
    getAsyncWithCallback(() => {
        let myObservable = getData();
    });
}
```

This is what I want to do:

```
mainFunction().subscribe((data) => { 
    // data is the data from getData()
});
```

What is the best way to achieve this, and chain in the error and completion form the inner?

Comment: If they don't return `myObservable` (or assign it somewhere), I don't think there's much you can do...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use promise and convert it into observable. I don't have IDE atm to provide you an example.

Comment: The callback is code I can change. I defined `myObservable` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution:

```
mainFunction(): Observable<any> {

    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        getAsyncWithCallback((): void => {
            getData().subscribe(observer);
        })
    })
}

mainFunction().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}));
```

Comment: That will create an observable of observables since `getData` returns an `Observable`.  I think you need to throw a `mergeMap/flatMap` in there somewhere.

Comment: I changed it to return an observable (whoops!), I am curious about why a merge or flat map?

Comment: I think it's better to write `getData().subscribe(observer)` instead of using operator as @Pace suggested

Comment: Well, what you have now will not chain errors or completion from the source observable to the observer.  Also, I think you mean `observer.next` and not `Observer.next`.  @Oles Savluk has a good point too (would chain all the events) but I still don't like it because it forces a subscription on the inner observable, even if no one subscribes to the outer one.

Comment: I see. Your right, about the errors and complete, and I didn't think it would force the subscription before the function was invoked. Is the function  resolved directly after being defined? Im not sure I understand Oles point. what would `subscribe(observer)` do?

Comment: No, my solution will not force subscribtion on inner observable, it is still "cold" which means that the `Observable.create` body will be executed only after someone have subscribed to it. So it is totaly fine :)

Comment: @RavenDev look `.subscribe` accepts object with `Observer` interface and your `observer` variable realize that interface. So basically it would call `observer.next`, `observer.error`, `observer.complete` for you (instead of writing this manually as you did)

Comment: @Oles Savluk,  I think I see what you did and said. Am I making sense if I said, "The interface for subscribe allows three functions, which are equivalent to the next, complete, and error methods on the observer. So by placing the observer as subscribe's argument it assumes each function and doesn't invoke the subscription method and thereby keeps it cold."

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to return an Observable from `mainFunction`.

If getData returns some other type of object that is not an Observable, you will construct your own Observable with [Observable.create](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create):

```
function mainFunction() {
  return Observable.create((obs) => {
    getAsyncWithCallback(() => {
      getData()
        .subscribe((data) => { obs.next(data); })
        .catch((err) => { obs.error(err) });
    });
  });
}

mainFunction().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

From the docs:

> create converts an onSubscription function to an actual Observable. Whenever someone subscribes to that Observable, the function will be called with an Observer instance as a first and only parameter
>
> Calling next with a value will emit that value to the observer.
>
> Most of the times you should not need to use create, because existing operators allow you to create an Observable for most of the use cases. That being said, create is low-level mechanism allowing you to create any Observable, if you have very specific needs.

There's also [Observable.from](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) which will create Observables from arrays, array-like objects, iterators, Observable-like objects and Promises.

Comment: The first option doesn't solve this, as I need to call `getAsyncWithCallback()`. As for the second option, it would not chain errors and completion. Will add this to my question.

Comment: @Grey not sure what you mean by that, in your example you aren't handling the failing case of the callback, this should be a good start though and you can use obs.error() or obs.complete() to signal an error or completion of the observable.

Comment: @RudolfOlah you can't execute `.catch` after `.subscribe` and you don't send completion. It is better to write `.subscribe(obs)` as I've described in the comments for another answer

Comment: @OlesSavluk thx, no console at the moment to test this. I wonder if the stackoverflow runnable code thing could be used....also perhaps we should create a community wiki answer so your comments can show up as part of the answer